# Different results for compilers: (gcc 4.8.1) and gcc( 4.3.2)

Tags: c++, c, gcc, pow

I submitted same solution for problem on an online judge on different compilers for C++.On gcc(4.3.2),I got WA, while same solution when submitted on gcc(4.8.1) got TLE.

Is it that 4.3.2 is faster but I think performance wise latest versions should outperform previous ones or is it the floating point anomalies in two compilers because problem require calculation of nth root of a 64-bit number and I am using long double and long long data types with pow function.I used something like:

```
    long long root,n;
    long double rad,rcnd;
    root = (long long)pow(rad,rcnd); where rcnd = 1.0/n;
```

Comment: you have provided too few information, but it is either a compiler bug, or you have UB

Comment: Actually its an ongoing contest,but I assure you there is nothing more in the code apart from one modular multiplication and addition.Sorry but what's UB.

Comment: UB = undefined behaviour. You could read http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html and http://blog.regehr.org/archives/213

Comment: Provide a small example of the calculation actually going wrong...

Comment: I may be ignorant of some common knowledge, but what do WA and TLE mean?

Comment: WA = Wrong Answer and TLE = Time Limit Exceeded.

Comment: @bolov There is more to C than undefined behavior and consistent behavior. There is unspecified behavior and implementation-defined behavior. See section 3. Terms, definitions, and symbols of the C99 standard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two versions of a same elementary function such as `pow()` only need each to be accurate to >0.5ULP to sometimes produce different results with the same arguments.

The C and C++ standards do not place any constraints on the accuracy on `pow()`. A proper implementation will try to be accurate to [1ULP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place), but that still leaves the possibility of the answer not being the best one and being different from the answer of another 1-ULP-accurate `pow()` function. Actually, several questions on this site are caused by `pow()` functions that are (in)accurate [to more than 1ULP](http://blog.frama-c.com/index.php?post/2013/04/06/Non-experts-need-accurate-floating-point-the-most), however ugly it may be and despite the ginormous means available to the provider of the inaccurate function.

So, in short: if you use `pow()`, the computations may differ between two compilers, although the compilers have the same implementation-defined characteristics (size of int, endianness, ...). If you use `pow()` in a numerically instable computation, the end results may differ arbitrarily.

The usual solution for reproducible results is to provide your own `pow()` function. However, if the difference is caused by numerically instable computations, this does not fix the root problem: the result, now reproducible, may still be meaningless.

Comment: That explains the strange behaviour.However I was checking both the upper and lower bounds i.e. if I got x(typecasted to integer,since we need integral root less than or equal to actual root) as nth root of y then I checked which of the (x+1),x,(x-1) is closest to y when raised to power n and this time I did'nt use pow.